# Webscrape salary from html element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract the salary from an html element

```
job_elements = soup.find_all('div', class_='job_seen_beacon')
for job in job_elements:
    title = job.find('h2', class_='jobTitle jobTitle-newJob css-bdjp2m eu4oa1w0')
    if title is None:
        job_titles.append('No job title')
    else:
        job_titles.append(title.text)
        
    company = job.find('div', class_='heading6 company_location tapItem-gutter companyInfo').text
    company_names.append(company)
    
    location = job.find('div', 'companyLocation').text
    locations.append(location)
    
    job_type = job.find('div', class_='metadata')
    if job_type is None:
        job_types.append('Not specified')
    else:
        job_types.append(job_type.text)

    salary = job.find('div', class_='attribute_snippet')
    print(job.text)
```

Using the code above prints out the job type instead of salary. Please how do I extract the salary?

screen shot of the html content and the page is below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the xpath of the salary field:

```
//div[@id="salaryInfoAndJobType"]/span[@class="css-2iqe2o eu4oa1w0"]
```

Comment: How do i implement this pleas?

Comment: @Donatus In this way: 
salary = job.find('div#salaryInfoAndJobType > span.css-2iqe2o.eu4oa1w0')

Comment: All I got back was None

Comment: Which library do you use for scraping?

Comment: I use BeautifulSoup and Requests